# Not asking for input

Tags: java

I have this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );
int selection = input.nextInt();
if (selection == 1) {
System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
String code = input.nextLine();
}
```

However, when it gets to Please enter a string, it doesnt ask for any input. It just goes to the rest of the program.

Comment: This is unrelated to your question but when performing console input like this you should use `print` instead of `println` so that what the user types in the console is after the colon (on the same line). `System.out.print("Please enter a string: ");`

Answer (score 7):

The `Scanner` waits at `nextInt()` until the user has pressed enter.  When that happens, it consumes the digits but **not** the new line character(s) itself.  Thus, the next call to `nextLine()` returns immediately with an empty `String` as its result.

This should fix it:

```
int selection = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
if (selection == 1) {
   System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
   String code = input.nextLine();
```

But my preferred way is to always use `nextLine` and do the parsing separately:

```
String selectionStr = input.nextLine();

//consider catching a NumberFormatException here to handle erroneous input
int selection = Integer.parseInt(selectionStr); 

if (selection == 1) {
   System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
   String code = input.nextLine();
   //...
```

Comment: +1 For suggesting to always use `nextLine` and parse what you want separately.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
input.nextLine();
```

after your nextInt();

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int selection = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
System.out.println(selection);
if (selection == 1) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
    String code = input.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Was this answer really necessary? You didn't even know the answer yourself until you read @Mark's answer.

Answer (score 0):

simple & graphical input :

```
String str=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Message","Title",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```